# delete a row in table view in swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I am trying to delete a row in table view. I have implemented the required methods but when i am swiping the row horizontally no delete button is coming. I have searched and I have found the same solution everywhere but it is not working in my case. I don't know where i am making mistake. Can anyone help me please?

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool 
{
    return true
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) 
{
     if editingStyle == .Delete 
     {
        dataHandler.deletePeripheral(indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
     }
}
```

Comment: i think u check function  syntax

Comment: func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus  I have used the same syntax as u suggested and i have also updated my question but still delete button is not coming.

Comment: I found that the answer below from @Nilesh worked.  I was missing the constraint to see the delete button.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If below coding is helpful for you,i will be happy

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool 
{
    return true
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) 
{
     if editingStyle == .Delete 
     {
        yourArray.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row) 
        self.tableView.reloadData()   
     }
}
```

**SWIFT 3.0**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool
{
    return true
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
   if editingStyle == .delete
   {
      yourArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
      tblDltRow.reloadData()
   }
}
```

You have to refresh the table.

Comment: tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade) is a better idea than reload the entire table

Comment: Painful to read reloadData(). Use "deleteRowAtIndexPaths" instead as Danny said

Answer (score 8):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete) {


            self.tableView.beginUpdates()
            self.arrayData.removeObjectAtIndex(indexPath.row) // also remove an array object if exists.
            self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths(NSArray(object: NSIndexPath(forRow: indexPath.row, inSection: 2)), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Left)
            self.tableView.endUpdates()

        }
```

Comment: The beginUpdate() and endUpdate() solved my problem where the app crashes when i just try to call DeleteRow in Swift 3

Answer (score 3):

Apply Autolayout Constraints to table view. The delete button is there but not displaying because of no auto layout

Comment: I had (some) constraints but apparently not enough.  Autolayout is an art, not a science. :)

Answer (score 3):

I struggled with this as well but finally found out a solution - I am running XCode 8.3.2. A lot of the answers I read were for older versions of XCode / Swift and many were for Objective-C.

The solution I found was to use the 'editActionsForRowAt' tool for UITableViews. Note: Everything else I read kept pointing me towards the '*commit editingStyle*' tool for UITableView, but I could never get it to work. Using editActionsForRowAt worked perfectly for me.

NOTE: 'postData' is the name of the Array that I added data to.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "Delete", handler: { (action, IndexPath) in
        // Remove item from the array
        postData.remove(at: IndexPath.row)

        // Delete the row from the table view
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath as IndexPath], with: .fade)
        })
        // set DeleteAction Button to RED (this line is optional - it simply allows you to change the color of the Delete button - remove it if you wish)
        deleteAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

    return [deleteAction]
}
```

I also have some code to add an 'EDIT button' alongside the Delete button:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    let editAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "Edit", handler: { (action, IndexPath) in
        //print("Edit tapped")
        })
        // Set EditAction button to blue (this line is not mandatory - it just sets the color of the Edit box to blue)
        editAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

    let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "Delete", handler: { (action, IndexPath) in
        //print("Delete tapped")
        // Remove item from the array
        postData.remove(at: IndexPath.row)

        // Delete the row from the table view
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath as IndexPath], with: .fade)
        })
        // set DeleteAction Button to RED (this line isn't mandatory - it just sets the color of the Delete box)
        deleteAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.green

    return [editAction, deleteAction]
}
```

EDIT: fixed format so code showed up in the grey box :)

Comment: commit edittingStyle works for me in Swift 3.. posted a working example up their.. your method workd for me too. it seems better.

Answer (score 2):

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) 
{
if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {
  numbers.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)    
  tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
}
}
```

Comment: i am using Table view not table view controllers i can't use override and i have implemented the method in same way but it's not working.

Answer (score 2):

for swift 3

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete {
        dataHandler.deletePeripheral(indexPath.row) 
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
        // - OR -
        // mTableView.reloadData() //mTableView is an outlet for the tableView
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i know what prob you are having . I think you just check your table constraints they may be wrong just recheck your auto layout constraints

Answer (score 0):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
                if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete { 
   yourArray.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)

   tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)

    }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool 
{
return true
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) 
 {
 if editingStyle == .Delete 
 {
    carsArray.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row) 
    self.tableView.reloadData()   
 }
 }
```