# How to delete a row from tableview using swift 2.2

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, delete-row

Am developing a app using swift in my app am using a tableview for adding contacts now i want to delete a row from the table view i have checked other stack overflow answer but nothing works out for me

code in my table view controller:

```
 func
tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool

  {

        return true
    }

  functableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)


  {

        if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete)
        {
            dataArray.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            self.FirstTableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

This one not helps for me and cell not even moving and displaying delete button

Note:1.am using left navigation drawer so I cant swipe left side

2.I want to swipe in right side only

3.am not adding any constraints to anything am using size classes and auto layout

Comment: Use this link :
https://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/delete-rows-table-view-ios8-swift

Comment: i have already followed that one but not helps me

Comment: Can you please set table view edit mode on? i think you have not set this property. Let me know after doing this thing.
Check Below Code : 
let tbl : UITableView; tbl.setEditing(true, animated: true)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [delete a row in table view in swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29294099/delete-a-row-in-table-view-in-swift)

Comment: i will check and update thanks

Comment: Side note (not related to the issue). In `commitEditingStyle` use **always** the table view instance passed in the first parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you check this delegate method you defined(I think you missed this)

```
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {

    return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete
}
```

and in cell commit style delete data like this:

```
        let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
        let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
        context.deleteObject(dataarray[indexPath.row] as NSManagedObject)
        dataarray.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        context.save(nil)
         self.FirstTableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: @rajkumar remove this function canEditRowAtIndexPath

Comment: it shows me error as nsmanaged object has no member remove object at index

Comment: store all value of nsmanagedobject(Core data you are using) into one nsmutableArray than it will work definately. use that array in tableview

Comment: how to do that ??

Comment: @rajkumar can you put cellforrowatindexpath method?

Comment: its already working there is a problem in my ipad touch anyway thank you for your time and patience