# Table Cell Not Swiping

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swipe

I'm developing a todo list app that links up with a `Realm` database, however when I'm trying to use the '`editingStyle`' method which allows users to swipe on the cell to delete the data from the UI & the Realm database the cell doesn't swipe, the app has 2 screens, this method works fine on one the first one but it does not work on the other screen, the cell works fine it just won't swipe.

My code:

```
    
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class CategoryViewController: UITableViewController {
    
    
    var categories: Results<Category>?
    let realm = try! Realm()
    
    

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        loadCategories()
        
      tableView.rowHeight = 60.0

    }
    
    //MARK: - Creating the table view cell

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
        return categories?.count ?? 0
        
    }
    

    
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        

   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CategoryCell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = categories?[indexPath.row].name ?? "No Categories Added Yet"

                return cell
        
    }
    
    //MARK: - This will remove a category from the UI & the Realm database, this is a built in swift method
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            if let  deleteAction  = categories?[indexPath.row] {
                do {
                    try realm.write({
                        realm.delete(deleteAction)
                    })
                } catch {
                print("Error deleting the cell \(error)")
                }
            }
        }
        
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    }


    
    //MARK: - TableView Delegate Methods
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToItems", sender: self)
    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let destinationVC = segue.destination as! TodoListViewController
        
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            destinationVC.selectedCategory = categories?[indexPath.row]
        }
    }
    
    
    
    //MARK: - Add New Categories

    @IBAction func addButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        
        var textField = UITextField()
        
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Add New Category", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
        
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Add", style: .default) { (action) in
            // What happens when user clicks add button

            
            let newCategory = Category()
            newCategory.name = textField.text!

            
            
            self.saveCategories(category: newCategory)
            
        }
        
        alert.addAction(action)
        
        alert.addTextField { (field) in
            textField = field
            textField.placeholder = "Add a new category"
        }
        
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        
    }
    

    //MARK: - Data Manipulation Methods
    
    func saveCategories(category: Category) {
        do {
            try realm.write({
                realm.add(category)
            })
        } catch {
            print("Error saving category \(error)")
        }
        
        tableView.reloadData()
        
    }
    
    func loadCategories() {
         categories = realm.objects(Category.self)
        
        tableView.reloadData()
  }


}
```

Comment: Not swiping or giving error as your code seems fine

Comment: See if implementing `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool` will fix your issue

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
```

Comment: tried that, didnt work, the code works fine in my other tableViewCell, it could be a problem with the simulator

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems correct. I think there's something wrong with `realm.delete(_:)` method which possibly throws an error which executes the `catch` block instead of deleting the row. Try to see if there is something wrong within the `try` block with a few print statements. And if all fails, try making the following changes

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            if let  deleteAction  = categories?[indexPath.row] {
                do {
                    try realm.write({
                        realm.delete(deleteAction)
                    })
                    // New snippet
                    tableView.deleteRows(at: indexPath, with: .fade) 
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                } catch {
                print("Error deleting the cell \(error)")
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Hey, I dont think it has something to do with the do & catch statement, nothing is printed to the debug console when i print something in them, the changes you suggested i did do but it gave me an error (Value of type 'UITableView' has no member 'remove') this exact code has works for me in another part of the app so i am a little confused here!

Comment: If it doesn't print there is something wrong with the code prior to the `print(_:)` statement. Could you reopen XCode, add some `print` statements in your functions calls like `ViewDidLoad(), do { try } catch`. I will edit the post

Comment: I found a similar thread to your question, see if the solutions there are the same. The [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29294099/delete-a-row-in-table-view-in-swift)

Comment: Thanks for that, i fixed the error, it was a problem in my main.storyboard, my code was fine in the end! appreciate the help